# is 0 even if even numbers are only defined in for natural numbers?

Tags: even-and-odd-functions

I have a question, if even numbers are only defined in natural numbers how 0 is even? I understand that even is the number divisible by 2 so 0 is even but it is defined this way only for natural numbers, for example there is no even numbers in complex numbers or negative numbers.

Comment: Even numbers are *not* only defined in natural numbers. $0,-2,-4,-6,-8,\dots$ are even.

Comment: There *are* even numbers in the complex numbers. All complex numbers are even, since $2\mid z$ means that $z=2w$ for some $w$. So take $w=z/2$.

Comment: Usually , "even" applies only to integers , but definitely not only to the natural numbers. An integer $n$ is even iff $\frac{n}{2}$ is an integer.